# Cordova access application files without application ID or access previous ID files

Tags: ios, cordova

Bit of a newbie when it comes to this so apologies if i'm using any of the wrong terms!

Whenever I build my application through cordova it assigns it a new application id like

```
2A7DA53D-C2B8-4804-9800-E664F6F93F23
```

My application is then storing images in the following directory

```
"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A7DA53D-C2B8-4804-9800-E664F6F93F23/Documents/reportimages_7/1535710208164.jpg"
```

Which works fine, but then once my application is updated, It tries to access images with a previous application id. For example, after updating the app and storing another image it stores in

```
"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/946CCCED-A1B3-4950-9C63-EFD040542115/Documents/reportimages_8/1535710897382.jpg"
```

I then use cordova file transfer to search for the above urls, and only the images in current application id folder of `946CCCED-A1B3-4950-9C63-EFD040542115` can be found!

Is there any way to skip the application id and just get the files straight from the '/Documents/' so instead it looks for

/Documents/reportimages_7/1535710208164.jpg
/Documents/reportimages_8/1535710897382.jpg

So it can always find the images even after the application ID has changed, or is there any way to always find the images with a changing application id?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly speaking, 
"2A7DA53D-C2B8-4804-9800-E664F6F93F23" folder is your Application's sandbox. Applications can access files only in their own sandbox (you would not want other apps to spy on your files, right?)

If you just update (override) your application, your Sandbox folder should not change. If you delete the app before installing new version, or change things like Bundle Identifier in the project, it will create new Sandbox.

Comment: Even when I am developing, if I simply rebuild the app in x-code it changes. Whenever I release a new version it changes so any users that update no longer have access to the previous files